# Is it possible to pass url parameters to HTML form having method=post?

Tags: html, url, post, coldfusion, parameters

Suppose that my form looks like this:

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="index.html">
   <input type="hidden" name="work" id="work1" value="20">
   <input type="hidden" name="play" id="play1" value="10">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Clicking submit sends `form.work` and `form.play` to index.html. There the values of work and play are used in a certain formula.

Now, I need to send out link to this page to several people with
predefined values of work and play. I tried this:

```
    www.mysite.com/index.html?work=20&play=10
```

Unfortunately this did not work. Any way to accomplish this?

Just for information, I am using a ColdFusion server.

Comment: Yes -- if the values are *read* correctly on the server.

Comment: _"this did not work"_ is meaningless - what code did you use? What error message did you receive?

Comment: (You probably want some variant of `<cfparam name="url.work" default="20" />` and `value="#HtmlEditFormat(url.work)#"` in the appropriate places.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I get the URL parameter & Value in Coldfusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904102/how-can-i-get-the-url-parameter-value-in-coldfusion)

Comment: Did not get a error message. The calculation on index.html simply did not happen with the passed values.

Comment: @AmanKejriwal note my answer below. ie. rename your 'index.html' to 'index.cfm'

Answer (score 6):

ColdFusion has a scope known as URL and a scope known as FORM, one for each HTTP method post/get respectively. Other languages jumble them together. Pros/cons aside, some CFML frameworks will actually combine them for you and make them available as part of the "request context."

What you need to do in this instance, is check the URL and the FORM scope for your values. Alternatively, you can change your form method to "get" so that you'll always have URL variables instead of form variables. In this way, you'll always use URL.variables instead of Form.variable

cfparam> sets default values for you so that the variables are there. It's like cfset>, but only sets whenever the value is missing.

So, in the top of your code:

```
//this sets the url value to always be blank unless something is passed in
<cfparam name="url.work" default="" />
//this sets the form value to the url value by default
<cfparam name="form.work" default="#url.work#" />
//you should never actually output user content to the screen, but here it is
<cfoutput>#form.work#</cfoutput>
```

As always, never trust what the user provides, sanitize the data before using it in the database or sending the content back to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that your attempting to use ColdFusion on an HTML page. 'index.html' will not be parsed by ColdFusion unless you've specifically altered your web server to direct .html files to be parsed by ColdFusion.

1. Change your 'index.html' to 'index.cfm'
2. Access the incoming variables via the URL or FORM scope. If the form was POSTED then use the FORM scope (form.work or form.play). If the form was done via url (?work=20&play=10) then use the URL scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the query string parameters in general.  They simply form part of the requested URL.

Whether or not the server-side framework makes them available is framework dependent.  I would expect that most frameworks would expose them, even if the request is a POST request.  The are available in ASP.Net.  I'm not sure about Cold Fusion.

> method="post"

informs the browser to place the form variables as post parameters in the HTTP request.  It does not preclude you from also including query string variables.

Answer (score 0):

variables in the urls are called `GET` variables, there must be some way in ColdFusion to retrieve them.